# Value Error when trying to visualize an image

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, keras

I´m trying to visualize some images belonging to different classes. The classes are `class0,class1,class2` and they mean X-ray pictures with healthy, covid and pneumonia lungs respectively. As an example, see picture below of a covid lung:

[image]

I´ve created three datasets containing the training, test and validation data. Please, see below the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Creating three dataframes reading .txt files
trainingfile = pd.read_table('data/training.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
testingfile = pd.read_table('data/testing.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
validationfile = pd.read_table('data/validation.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
#Change 0,1,2 to categorical class class0,class1,class2
trainingfile = trainingfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])
testingfile = testingfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])
validationfile = validationfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])

#Final training, test and validation data
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=trainingfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256), batch_size=32)
test_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=testingfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256), batch_size=15)
validation_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=validationfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256), batch_size=21)
```

Now, the code to visualize one picture:

```
first_image = train_generator[0]
first_image = np.array(first_image, dtype='float')
pixels = first_image.reshape((28, 28))
plt.imshow(pixels, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b237e88f96dd> in <module>
      1 first_image = train_generator[0]
----> 2 first_image = np.array(first_image, dtype='float')
      3 pixels = first_image.reshape((28, 28))
      4 plt.imshow(pixels, cmap='gray')
      5 plt.show()

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,256,256,3) into shape (32)
```

Furthermore, is there any way to visualize an image corresponding to a specific class?

If instead of `first_image= first_image[0], I do first_image= first_image[0][0]`. Then the error that pops up is:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0664c7dc8c6b> in <module>
      1 first_image = train_generator[0][0]
      2 first_image = np.array(first_image, dtype='float')
----> 3 pixels = first_image.reshape((28, 28))
      4 plt.imshow(pixels, cmap='gray')
      5 plt.show()

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6291456 into shape (28,28)
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error pop up? Please update your post with the full error trace.

Comment: Yes, errors in isolation mean nothing, full traceback is required.

Comment: In any case, `train_generator` does not return a single image, as you seem to expect, but a batch of 32 images, hence the shape of the result `(32,256,256,3)`. Try getting `train_generator[0][0]` instead.

Comment: hi guys, code amended according to your suggestions.